# How to change color of hovered menu item in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a beginner. I have written this code on JSFiddle. I want to set the color of selected menu-item to yellow and other menu-items to aqua. Please guide me.

```
$(function () {
    $('nav ul li').not("nav ul li ul li").hover(function (e) {
        $("nav ul li ul").hide();
        $(this).children('ul').stop().toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
$(document).hover(function () {
    $("nav ul li ul").hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xc3z016x/)

Comment: why do it jquery when you can do it css?

Comment: `li:hover {
    color: yellow;
}`

Comment: Good suggestion. Let me try that.

Comment: `li{color:aqua;} li:hover{color: yellow;}`

Comment: @divy3993 your trick works. However, what to do if I want to do it using jQuery?

Comment: Have a look at the answer i posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The CSS Way:**

```
li
{
   color:aqua;
}

li:hover
{
   color:yellow;
}
```

**The JQuery Way**

```js
$(".someClass li").css("color","aqua");
$(".someClass li").hover(function(){ $(this).css("color","yellow");},function(){$(this).css("color","aqua");});
```

```css
ul li
{
  list-style:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="someClass">
  <li>Text1</li>
  <li>Text2</li>
  <li>Text3</li>
</ul>
```